# Пагинация в selenium

Tags: python, парсер, selenium

Пытаюсь спарсить сайт dns-shop.ru. Удалось получить информацию по первой странице, но вот перейти на следующую страницу не удается.

Вот сам код

```html
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import requests
# import csv

# csv = smartphone_from_dns-shop

start_time = time.time()
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.headless = False
driver_service = Service(executable_path=r"C:\Users\Кирилл\PycharmProjects\DNS_parser\chromedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=driver_service)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(20)

url = "https://www.dns-shop.ru/catalog/17a8a01d16404e77/smartfony/?p=1"
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) "
                  "Chrome/100.0.4896.60 Safari/537.36",
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,"
              "application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9 "
}


def start_browser(url):
    # Открывем ссылку url
    driver.get(url=url)

def get_content():
    # Получем html данной страницы, вытаскиваем из него название и цену и сохраняем в список smartphones
    soup = BS(driver.page_source, "lxml")
    time.sleep(1)
    products = soup.find_all(class_="catalog-product__name ui-link ui-link_black")
    prices = soup.find_all("div", class_="product-buy__price")
    smartphones = []
    for i in range(0, len(products)):
        smartphones.append(
            {
                'title': products[i].text,
                'price': prices[i].text,
            }
        )

    return smartphones

def parser():
    #Пагинация сайта, вставка списка со страницы в общий список

    # pagination = int(input('Количество страниц для парсинга:'))
    pagination = 1
    html = requests.get(url)

    if html.status_code == 200:
        list_smartphones = []
        for page in range(1, pagination+1):
            list_smartphones.extend(get_content())
            button_pagination_next = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'pagination-widget__page-link pagination-widget__page-link_next ').get_attribute('href')
            print(button_pagination_next)
            # print("Перешли на следующую страницу")

    else:
        print("Сайт недоступен")

    return list_smartphones


if __name__ == "__main__":
    start_browser(url)
    result = parser()
    print(result)
```

Пытался найти ссылку на элемент пагинации в html через

```
button_pagination_next = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 
'pagination-widget__page-link pagination-widget__page-link_next ').get_attribute('href')
```

но выдает ошибку

```html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Проекты\DNS_parser\main.py", line 73, in <module>
    result = parser()
  File "F:\Проекты\DNS_parser\main.py", line 61, in parser
    button_pagination_next = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'pagination-widget__page-link pagination-widget__page-link_next ').get_attribute('href')
  File "C:\Users\Кирилл\PycharmProjects\DNS_parser\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 1248, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "C:\Users\Кирилл\PycharmProjects\DNS_parser\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 425, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Кирилл\PycharmProjects\DNS_parser\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 247, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".pagination-widget__page-link pagination-widget__page-link_next "}
  (Session info: chrome=100.0.4896.60)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    Ordinal0 [0x004E7413+2389011]
    Ordinal0 [0x00479F61+1941345]
    Ordinal0 [0x0036C658+837208]
    Ordinal0 [0x003991DD+1020381]
    Ordinal0 [0x0039949B+1021083]
    Ordinal0 [0x003C6032+1204274]
    Ordinal0 [0x003B4194+1130900]
    Ordinal0 [0x003C4302+1196802]
    Ordinal0 [0x003B3F66+1130342]
    Ordinal0 [0x0038E546+976198]
    Ordinal0 [0x0038F456+980054]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00699632+1727522]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0074BA4D+2457661]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0057EB81+569713]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0057DD76+566118]
    Ordinal0 [0x00480B2B+1968939]
    Ordinal0 [0x00485988+1989000]
    Ordinal0 [0x00485A75+1989237]
    Ordinal0 [0x0048ECB1+2026673]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x7591FA29+25]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x770A7A7E+286]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x770A7A4E+238]


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Поиск в гугле направил на то, что страница не прогружается, поэтому добавил задержку

```
driver.implicitly_wait(20)
```

но ничего не поменялось.

Comment: В "https://www.dns-shop.ru/catalog/17a8a01d16404e77/smartfony/?p=1"  меняем '?p=1' на '?p=2' и т. д. вот вам и переход на следующию страницу

Comment: Да, спасибо. Это оказалось проще сделать

Answer (score 1):

**selenium** не понимает когда ему дают несколько классов 'pagination-widget__page-link pagination-widget__page-link_next '), возьмите один "pagination-widget__page-link_next"

```
    driver = Chrome('C:\\......\chromedriver.exe')
    driver.implicitly_wait(10) 
    driver.get('https://www.dns-shop.ru/catalog/17a9f3da16404e77/pulty-du-dlya-televizorov/')  # Запускаем браузер
    # Находим кнопку перехода на следующую страницу
    but_end= driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "pagination-widget__page-link_next")
    but_end.click() # Жмем ее
```

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, если цель не автотестирование пользовательского интерфейса, то не имеет особого смысла имитировать поведение пользователя в виде нажатия на какие-то элементы страницы. Передайте селениуму абсолютный адрес целевой страницы, в вашем случае для второй страницы - `https://www.dns-shop.ru/catalog/17a8a01d16404e77/smartfony/?p=2`

Во-вторых, если вышенаписанное верно, то вероятно вам и Selenium не особо нужен, по крайней мере в парсинге этого конкретного сайта (но это не точно, предположение). Для получения статического HTML лучше, быстрее и надёжнее  справится, например, библиотека requests.

Comment: сайт дмнамический нет статического HTML